# aws fifo queue cannot receive messageGroupID

Tags: amazon-web-services, fifo

I want to distinguish the messages after retreiving from aws fifo sqs for routing to correct processor. And I planned to utilize the **MessageGroupId** , which I set while sending the request.
I am using Java sdk.
sendMessageRequest.setMessageGroupId(messageGroupId);

[Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/ReceiveMessageRequest.html#setMessageAttributeNames-java.util.Collection-) says it can be retrieved as request parameter of AttributeName

MessageGroupId - Returns the value provided by the sender that calls the SendMessage action. Messages with the same MessageGroupId are returned in sequence.
However, I could not find the correct way/method to do so. There is no attribute 
**MessageGroupId** present and size is 0.

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();

for (Message message : messages) 
{  
System.out.println("    Size getAttributes:          " +   message.getAttributes() .size());
}
```

Only if I set any attribute explicitly then it is retreivable (like   with MESSAGEPRIORITY), but how to receive the values of attributes like MessageGroupId?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: works with message.getAttributes() after receiveMessageRequest.withAttributeNames("All"), as suggested in below reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell SQS which attributes you want it to give you, before `getAttributes()` will be able to show them to you.

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest.withAttributeNames("All")).getMessages();
```

Note that SQS messages have two different kinds of attributes.  *Attributes* are system-generated (like `MessageGroupId`), while *Message Attributes* are user-generated, custom key/value pairs included when the message is sent but transported external to the message body itself.

Comment: Thanks much @Michael. Works.

Comment: @snijhi great!  Don't forget to tick the checkmark to signify that the answer has been "accepted."